# How to set IAM policy for a project using Google Cloud Resource Manager package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, project, google-cloud-iam

## Problem

I'm using the google-cloud-resource-manager to create projects. I would like to update the IAM policy of the project to ad a new user to the owner roole.

Here's how I do:

```py
async def set_iam_policy(project_id, user_id):
    client = ProjectsAsyncClient()
    project_ressource = 'projects/{}'.format(project_id)
    iam_policy : Policy = await client.get_iam_policy(resource=project_ressource)
    owner : Binding = iam_policy.bindings[0]
    owner.members.append('user:{}'.format(user_id))
    updated_policy =await client.set_iam_policy(resource=project_ressource)
```

## Explanations

1. I get thee project iam policy
2. I edit the policy given to add the specified user as an owner
3. I try to update the IAM poolicy for the given project, it breaks here

The `set_iam_policy` takes as argument a ressource string (exemple `projects/myprojectid`
but I can't pass the policy to this object, there is not fields for that.
Am I missing something?

## Documentation

You can find the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudresourcemanager/latest/resourcemanager_v3/projects.html) and the [source code](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudresourcemanager/latest/_modules/google/cloud/resourcemanager_v3/services/projects/async_client.html#ProjectsAsyncClient.set_iam_policy) associated with the `set_iam_policy` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```py
request = SetIamPolicyRequest(
    resource=project_ressource,
    policy=iam_policy,
)

updated_policy = await client.set_iam_policy(
   resource=project_ressource,
   request=request,
)
```

> **NOTE** retained typo in `project_ressource`

> **NOTE** You should **not** assume that `bindings[0]` corresponds to `roles/owners`.

Comment: in the `client.set_iam_policy`, `resource` field is not required since it is already given in the SetIamPolicyRequest